# Determine protocol of a given sql connection

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to see what connection protocol a given connection to sql 2008 is using (be it shared memory, named pipes, or tcp/ip)...I'm not seeing this info in the sql activity monitor. Is there some place I can view this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) DMV has the physical connection info, including protocol used:

```
select net_transport from sys.dm_exec_connections 
where session_id = @@spid
```